# How to calculate value from one column between row 1 to row N, with Scala/spark data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Here is the example dataframe,

```
city,  LONG,   LAT
city1, 100.30, 50.11
city2, 100.20, 50.16
city3, 100.20, 51
..
```

We need to calculate distance between `city1` and all cities, and `city2` and all cities, and iterate for each city. Function 'distance' is created. Then we can use for loop each line or use data dict in Python.

For dataframe, how can apply for loop or data dict concept to dataframe?

for example in python. (Not all codes shown here.)

```
citydict = dict()
citydict2=copy.deepcopy(citydict)

for city1, pciinfo1 in citydict.items():
    pcicity2.pop(pci1)
    for city2, cityinfo2 in citydict2.items():
            s=distancecalc(cityinfo1,cityinfo2)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything with spark/pyspark ?

Comment: yes, my environment is scala on spark. was trying with pyspark earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crossJoin` method does the trick. It returns the cartesian product of two dataframes. The idea is to cross the Dataframe with itself.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.as("thisDF")
  .crossJoin(df.as("toCompareDF"))
  .filter($"thisDF.city" =!= $"toCompareDF.city")
  .withColumn("distance", calculateDistance($"thisDF.lon", $"thisDF.lat", $"toCompareDF.lon", $"toCompareDF.lat"))
  .show
```

First of all, we add an alias to our Dataframe so that we can identify it when we perform the join. Next step is to perform the `crossJoin` over the same Dataframe. Note that we're also adding an alias to this new Dataframe. To delete those tuples that match the same city, we filter by the city column.

Finally, we apply a Spark User Defined Function, passing the necessary columns to calculate the distance. This is the declaration of the UDF:

```
def calculateDistance = udf((lon1: Double, lat1: Double, lon2: Double, lat2: Double) => {
  // add calculation here
})
```

And that's all. Hope it helps.

Comment: exactly it is. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Can you please accept my answer? :)